Grammatical term for sentence construction when verb is not repeated in subsequent clauses
A chapter of "Burlington English", a British publisher's text book, discusses the role played by the people behind the scenes. The reality cookery show's Series Producer has this to say about the show:

"Our show is more or less "real".
We don't follow a script, tell participants how to behave, or create conflict between them.
We just put them on the set and tell then to go for it."

In the bold sentence,  the verb "don't" applies to three consecutive clauses (as I understood it)

we don't follow a script
we don't tell participants how to behave.
we don't create conflict between them.

What grammatical term describes this construction where the verb is not repeated?
Does "nor" work better instead of "or" in the third clause, as it is in the negative ?

Nor needs to follow neither, so or is fine in the quoted sentence. "We neither [do] A, B nor C."

This was answered in Can "elide" be used to mean "omit words".

Ellipsis is the technically correct word to use when talking about the omission of words. I don’t think it’s going to hurt anything to
use a less technical term like “omission” or “implied word”.
I do think using “elide” or “elision” when you really mean “ellipsis”
would be harmful, because in a linguistic context “elision” has a
distinct meaning.
Being sloppy about the usage of technical terms can make things
difficult for learners already saddled with terms that are sometimes
unique to EFL courses. It doesn’t help that the words seem similar and
are both about omissions.
In linguistics, an elision or deletion is the omission of one or more
sounds (such as a vowel, a consonant, or a whole syllable) in a word
or phrase.
In linguistics, ellipsis (from the Greek: ἔλλειψις, élleipsis,
"omission") or an elliptical construction is the omission from a
clause of one or more words that are nevertheless understood in the
context of the remaining elements.
The ellipsis on the main site has over 480 questions already, the
elision tag has under 20 (and I found at least one of those tagged
incorrectly). The description of those tags were added in 2013, so
there is some history there worth considering.

In that sentence, I believe "or" would be more appropriate than "nor".  From quickanddirtytips.com

To summarize, "nor" often pairs up with "neither," but not always.
When it comes to other negative words (besides "neither"), use “or” if
the second part of the negative is a noun, adjective, or adverb
phrase. If it’s a verb phrase, choose either “nor” or “or.” If you’re
unsure which one to use, consider saying, “and no” or “and not” for
the second part.


Please use quotation markdown to highlight quotes. It's not clear from your use of """.

OP had enquired about the deletion of the verb "don't" in the sentence:

We don't follow a script, tell participants how to behave, or create conflict between them.

"Gapping" is a linguistic technique that omits repeated verbs in coordinated clauses to avoid repetition.
In the sentence 'We don't follow a script, tell participants how to behave, or create conflict between them,'
the verb 'don't' is implied for the subsequent clauses.

Reference Collins dictionary:.
gapping.
in British English.
noun
(in transformational grammar) a rule that deletes repetitions of a verb, as in the sentence

Bill voted for Smith, Sam for McKay, and Dave for Harris.
Mary brought the bread, John the cheese, and Bill the wine.



Great answer! From wikipedia: "In linguistics, gapping is a type of ellipsis". So "ellipsis" isn't wrong, but less specific.

@Sam I am going to accept your answer. Although it is correct, I think it is too long.
